# About log4j.xml NullAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have done some Googling around it but couldn't find any relevant information. `log4j` supports a bunch of log `appenders`, there's documentation all over the net about `ConsoleAppender` and `FileAppender`, but there are very little or no information about appenders such as `NullAppender`, `JDBCAppender` etc. I am particularly interested about `NullAppender`.

```
<appender name="???" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender">
<appender name="???" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
```

Does anyone have any specific info on these? especially on the `NullAppender`?

I started looking [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `NullAppender`, there's not a lot of doc largely because there's nothing to configure:  you can define one with `<appender name="foo" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender"/>` and that's about it. From the Javadoc:

> A NullAppender merely exists, it never outputs a message to any device.

There aren't a lot a different ways to do nothing. (It exists so that you can trash output without modifying too much of your config.)

For the `JDBCAppender`, the Javadoc is here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html
The `param` tags in the XML config correspond to setters in the Java class, but note the big red warning at the top of the Javadoc:

> WARNING: This version of JDBCAppender is very likely to be completely replaced in the future. Moreoever, it does not log exceptions.

So maybe not the best class to be relying on, given that log4j v2.0 is currently in beta, and that a cursory look over the [alpha release](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j/2.0-alpha2/log4j-2.0-alpha2.pom) seems to indicate that it doesn't exist in v2.

Comment: Well, I wasn't too optimistic about this either :) but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Annjawn If you really need to log to your database, your best bet is probably to [roll your own](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Appenders), either by extending an existing one, or just implementing the Appender interface.

Comment: Yeah, I would have thought doing so but for now I am happy with console and file appenders.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google for this class will get you

[Nullappender](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v4r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/logging_procedures.htm)

So essentially if you use the NullAppender your log messaged are written nowhere.

Comment: How convenient. Why would I use this if I don't want to append my log messages anywhere? Any specific example?

Comment: Let's say I have a hierarchical tree of categories. I want all categories at a certain level or below to not log anything. I can pinpoint that level and set the threshold to NONE. That doesn't solve my problem because I could have dozens of sub-category declarations overriding the NONE setting. To solve this, I can set the pinpoint category's appender to NullAppender and appender additivity to false. When I change my mind later, reverse the changes. Both times I was able to leave all my sub-category declarations alone. Admittedly, comment toggling could achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The **NullAppender** basically does nothing, like others have already pointed out. I just wanted to layout some details.

```
        AppenderSkeleton implements Appender {
          ...
          @Override
          public synchronized void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
            ...
          }
          ...
          abstract protected void append(LoggingEvent event);
        }

        public class NullAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
          public static String s;
          public String t;
          ...
          @Override
          public void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
            if(layout != null) {
              t = layout.format(event);
              s = t;
            }
          }
          @Override
          public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
          }
```

See also: [Source-NullAppender](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/log4j/log4j-1.2.8/org/apache/log4j/performance/NullAppender.java.html#line.48) & [Source-AppenderSkeleton](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/log4j/log4j-1.2.8/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.java.html)

What happens at each and every log.trace/debug/... call is

```
 -> org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(String fqcn, Priority level, Object message, Throwable t) 
 -> org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(LoggingEvent event)
 -> org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent event) is called on each Appender within that Logger
 -> org.apache.log4j.Appender.doAppend(LoggingEvent event)
 which is NullPointers implementation of doAppend in this case.
```

As you see, the NullAppender takes away the synchronization, NullAppender.doAppend produces some overhead, but it is very little in most scenarios.

As for **JDBCAppender** it should not be used.

```
       WARNING: This version of JDBCAppender
       is very likely to be completely replaced in the future. Moreoever,
       it does not log exceptions.
```

See: [JDBC-Appender-Source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.java.html) Line 34-36

As an **alternative** you might want to check out [clusterlog](http://www.clusterlog.net)